# Update quill editor content by dynamic data in svelte

Tags: svelte, quill, svelte-component

I need to add quill editor to my svelte projects. I found [this link](https://svelte.dev/repl/839ad6a3e1e24b149099c704e18df476?version=3.32.3) online and followed his idea.

I installed his version from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tadashi/svelte-editor-quill. Now the editor has initialized with given initial value.

But I need to update the editor value dynamically and the value is changing, but the editor is not functioning properly as it is going to read-only mode.

I just want to update editor data on call `add()` function. How can I do this?

That's how imported editor:

```
import {Editor, quill} from '@tadashi/svelte-editor-quill';
```

and rest code to initialize it:

```
let editorData =  "";

var toolbarOptions = [
   ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],        // toggled buttons
   ['link','blockquote', 'code-block'],
   [{ 'header': 1 }, { 'header': 2 }],               // custom button values
   [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
   [{ 'script': 'sub'}, { 'script': 'super' }],      // superscript/subscript
   [{ 'indent': '-1'}, { 'indent': '+1' }],          // outdent/indent
   [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }],                         // text direction
   [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],  // custom dropdown
   [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
   [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],          // dropdown with defaults from theme
   [{ 'font': [] }],
   [{ 'align': [] }],
   ['clean'],                                        // remove formatting button
   ['link', 'image'],
];

const options = {
   // debug: 'info',
   modules: {
    toolbar: toolbarOptions
   },
   placeholder: "Write here..",
   theme: "snow",
   // readOnly: true,
};

function onTextChange(event) {
   editorData = 'fhgfgh';
   console.log(event.detail)
}

function add(){
   editorData = "Apenas um show dfghdfgh";
   console.log(editorData);
}
```

Editor in HTML:

```
<Editor {options} on:text-change={onTextChange} bind:data={editorData} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unfortunately not a very usable package.

The `data` property is not bindable and can only be used to set the initial value, if you change it later it will overwrite the editor element.

The component also does *not* expose the Quill instance which would give you access to its full API (like [`insertText`](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#inserttext)). The only possible interaction is getting the `text-change` event.

You could recreate the entire `Editor` when the data changes programmatically but that is not a good approach. It can potentially cause layout shifts, unwanted scrolling and is wasteful.

I would recommend writing your own Svelte wrapper or find a better alternative.

Comment: thanks for your comment @H.B . yes did it with tiny mce ..

Comment: @R.alim If this sufficiently answers the question, you can accept it using the checkmark to the left of the answer.